# PHP MySQL search with multi tags

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am creating a website where users can upload images with lots of tags, and there is also a search function to show posts with those tags, but I'm having trouble displaying the posts with the tags: its just too confusing for me with two different `MySQL` tables for the image, then the tags.

My MySQL table for images:

```
id
img_url
img_id
title
description
username
status
positive        
negative        
date_time
```

My MySQL table for tags:

```
id
img_id
tag_name
```

My PHP code:

```
/* put the tags in the url */
if(isset($_POST['s_submit'])){
    $tags = strip_tags(stripcslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['search_box'])));
    header("location:home.php?search={$tags}");
}
/* search image tags */
if(isset($_GET['search'])){
    $tags = strip_tags(stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_GET['search'])));
    if(!empty($tags)){
        $tags_o = explode("%27", $tags);
        $tags_c = count($tags_o);
        for ($i=0; $i < $tags_c ; $i++){
            $con = new mysqli($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass,$db_name);
            $tags_query = $con->query("SELECT * FROM tags WHERE tag_name LIKE '$tags_o[$i]'");
            $tags_array = mysqli_fetch_array($tags_query);
            $tags_i = $tags_array['img_id'];
            $post_query = $con->query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE img_id='$tags_i'");
            while($post_array = mysqli_fetch_array($post_query)){
                echo '
                <div class="post">
                    <a href="#">
                        <div class="post-img">
                            '.$post_array['img_url'].'
                        </div>
                    </a>
                    <div class="post-btm">
                        <p>From: <a href="#">Admin</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                ';
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo '<div class="search-error"><p>Nothing to show here, try to search something!</p></div>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help, you can get all the data with 1 query.

```
$tags = explode("%27", $tags);
 $array = [];

 foreach ($tags as $val) {
   $array[] = "'%".$val."%'"; // sanitize val to prevent sql injection
 }
 $string = implode(' OR t.tag_name LIKE ', $array);

$images = $con->query("SELECT i.* FROM images as i 
                        INNER JOIN tags ON tag.img_id = i.id AS t
                       WHERE t.tag_name LIKE {$string} GROUP BY i.id");
```

Didnt test it, and try to use prepared statments to prevent sql injections